# code to communicate between two microcontrollers

Tags: assembly, io, spi, 8051

I'm trying to implement something similar to the SPI (serial programming interface) to communicate between two mini microcontrollers (chip #AT89c2051). Since the on-board serial port is already in use by each microcontroller for other purposes, all I have available as communication wires is 10 bits total. eight are address bits, and the other two are control bits. Each microcontroller runs at a different speed (18.432Mhz and 20Mhz) due to crystal pricing and compatibility with computers.

My code is able to work partially but not correctly.

Here are the constants used throughout my program:

```
NUMBYTESIO EQU 10h ;set transfer bytes to 16
TEMP EQU 30h ;temporary pointer for register saves
DATAPTR EQU 31h ;data pointer for commands
RINT EQU P3.2 ;INTerrupt to tell slave that master is ready
RACK EQU P3.3 ;Remote busy INTerrupt to tell master that slave is busy
```

This is the code that is executed on the master with the 18.432Mhz speed when it makes a request to the slave:

```
request: ;start request from slow microcontroller
  mov R0,#DATAPTR ;set R0 to data pointer (address 30h)
  mov R7,#0h ;clear counter register
  dorequest:
mov P1,@R0   ;read local register data from memory location and store in the outgoing 8 bits
clr RINT     ;clear request interrupt to let remote know data is ready
jb RACK,$    ;wait till remote acknowledges data
mov P1,#0FFh ;set data line high to enable remote to send data
setb RINT    ;set request interrupt to let remote know we're ready for data
jnb RACK,$   ;wait till remote understands were ready
mov @R0,P1   ;overwrite memory location with new data
inc R0       ;advance memory location pointer
inc R7       ;add 1 to # of bytes processed
  cjne R7,#NUMBYTESIO,dorequest ;if # bytes processed < 16, repeat process
ret         ;end the request
```

and this is how the slave processes the request from the master, but the last line is reti instead of ret because remotereq is called from the interrupt handler which is triggered by the master:

```
remotereq: ;fast micro received request from slow micro and RINT is low
  mov P1,#0FFh ;sanity check: make data line high to let remote send data
  ;next 5 lines save R1...R7 registers onto stack
  mov TEMP,#7h 
  saveb: 
  push TEMP
  dec TEMP
  jnz saveb
  mov R7,#0h
  rrr:          ;start reception of request
mov P1,#0FFh    ;make data line high
jb RINT,$           ;wait until remote has data (it will set this line low)
mov A,P1            ;get the data
clr RACK            ;and send an acknowledgement to remote
jnb RINT,$      ;wait until remote is ready for data
lcall doradcmds     ;process byte
mov P1,A            ;take result of the byte as data to send back
setb RACK           ;send acknowledgement to remote to let it know data is ready
mov R6,#0FFh ;start data timeout of 255 clock cycles (about 100-ish microseconds)
djnz R6,$
inc R7 ;increment counter
  cjne R7,#NUMBYTESIO,rrr ;repeat process for all remaining bytes
  mov P1,#0FFh ;set data line high to avoid contention
  mov TEMP,#7h
  saveb2:
  pop TEMP
  dec TEMP
  jnz saveb2
reti
```

And this is where the slave does all the command processing:

```
;PROC COMMANDS
; R7=LIVE byte#, A=live data, R6=bad

doradcmds:
  cjne R7,#0h,majorcmd ;see if byte # is the first
mov R2,A ;byte is first. store command in R2
mov A,#40h ;returned result starts with @
ret
  majorcmd:
  mov TEMP,R7 ;copy current byte #...
  mov R3,TEMP ;... into R3
  cjne R2,#A5h,notest ;run test command if 1st byte is A5h
djnz R3,notestp1
  mov R5,A    ;store first command parameter into R5
  mov A,#40h  ;return an @ in result
  ret
notestp1:
djnz R3,notestp2
  mov R4,A    ;store second parameter into R4
  mov A,#40h  ;return an @ in result (not working)
  ret
notestp2:
djnz R3,notesto1
  mov A,R4 ;return value of R4 for 3rd byte 
  ret
notesto1:
djnz R3,notesto2
  mov A,R5 ;return value of R5 for 4th byte 
  ret
notesto2:
  notest:
ret
```

And this is how the master makes a call to the request (front end code):

```
mov DATAPTR,#A5h
mov DATAPTR+1,#43h ;C
mov DATAPTR+2,#41h ;A
mov DATAPTR+3,#44h ;D
mov DATAPTR+4,#42h ;B
mov DATAPTR+5,#46h ;F
mov DATAPTR+6,#45h ;E
lcall request
```

And this is how the master retrieves the results:

```
mov A,DATAPTR
lcall outserbyte
mov A,DATAPTR+1
lcall outserbyte
mov A,DATAPTR+2
lcall outserbyte
mov A,DATAPTR+3
lcall outserbyte
mov A,DATAPTR+4
lcall outserbyte
mov A,DATAPTR+5
lcall outserbyte
mov A,DATAPTR+6
lcall outserbyte
```

And the serial port byte function is simple:

```
outserbyte:
  clr TI
  mov SBUF,A
  jnb TI,$
ret
```

Basically, the data I'm sending to the slave is:

```
A5h, 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'F', and 'E'. where A5h is a hexadecimal value.
```

The data I received back was:

```
'@', '@', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'F' and 'E'.
```

The speed of operation is acceptable but the data returned is incorrect. The data I expected to have returned as my command is a swap bytes function is this:

```
'@', '@', '@', 'A', 'C', 'F' and 'E'.
```

But I only care more about the first 5 bytes, particularly the 4th and 5th.
Is there a way I can fix my code to return the correct data?

Comment: Make sure your interrupt handler is not triggered again while its running.

Comment: I'll have to double check that. Other than disabling the interrupt check throughout the critical code, is there anything else I need to do?